# TabHost (Hide Tabhost From fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, tabs

[image]I have a tabhost which is places Inside my Main activity(Navigation Drawer).
In every Tab i have ViewPager.
ViewPager consist of different Fragments.
Inside those Fragments, I have to hide/show my TabHost.
But I dunno how to pass the TabHost from my Activity to fragment.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab1", R.string.textTabTitle1, R.drawable.icon_search, R.id.tab1);
    setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab2", R.string.textTabTitle1, R.drawable.icon_comment, R.id.tab2);
    setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab3", R.string.textTabTitle1, R.drawable.icon_car, R.id.tab3);


    final ViewPager pagerComment = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerComment);
    pagerComment.setAdapter(new AdapterTabComment(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    final ViewPager pagerSearch = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerSearch);
    pagerSearch.setAdapter(new AdapterTabSearch(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    tabsComment = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabsComment);
    tabsComment.setViewPager(pagerComment);
    setTextColor(0, tabsComment);

    tabsSearch = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabsSearch);
    tabsSearch.setViewPager(pagerSearch);
    setTextColor(0, tabsSearch);

    pagerComment.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            setTextColor(position, tabsComment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });


    pagerSearch.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            setTextColor(position,tabsSearch);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}});
    pagerSearch.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

Is that even possible?
Thank you..

Comment: Can u please attach screen shot so that i can help u to solve this problem...what u want actually?

Comment: okay wait... ill make some. thanks.

Comment: image posted.. what i want is Hide the Tab at the bottom when the recyclerview is scrolled. The recyclerview is declared inside the fragment while the tabhost is declared in my MyActivity(Navigation View)

Comment: yup make it static is one option bt some how not to use static for Controls as per android standards

Comment: Make setter getter method for Tabhos id and use in fragment i think it would be better idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare TabHost static and you can access in your fragment. I used this in my project.

Comment: Very helpful! thanks. I Solved it just declaring static. thanks

Comment: ii want hide the viewpager in Tablayout? how to do this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I dint get your question properly but i will answer the question as i understood

as you call Fragment faragment= new Fragment();
pass some keys to that fragmet as parameters so that on that basis you can hide or show the tabhostsinside the fragment. if i am wrong sorry..

Comment: How to do that? Can i Pass Ids ? Like the ID of TabHost?

Comment: i got your point you want to hide the bottom tab  on scroll itself rite or you want to hide the tab when you enter that particular fragment

Comment: Yes. but the tab is declared in my activity, and i will hide it when the recyclerview in other fragment is scrolled.